# Getting cursor position in a UITextView on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

We have a UITextView in our iPhone app which is editable.  We need to insert some text at the cursor location when the users presses some toolbar buttons but can't seem to find a documented (or undocumented) method of finding the current location of the cursor.

Does anybody have any ideas or has anybody else achieved anything similar?

Comment: Of note is that textField.selectedRange.location will not return the location if requested in textViewDidBeginEditing:textField unless you get it after a delay.

Answer (score 31):

Like drewh said, you can use UITextView's selectedRange to return the insertion point. The length of this range is always zero. The example below shows how to it.

```
NSString *contentsToAdd = @"some string";
NSRange cursorPosition = [tf selectedRange];
NSMutableString *tfContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[tf text]];
[tfContent insertString:contentsToAdd atIndex:cursorPosition.location];
[theTextField setText:tfContent];
[tfContent release];
```

Comment: Note that with iPhone 3.0, it is no longer true that the length of the range is always zero. If the user has text selected, then the length will be non-zero. In this case, you may want to use replaceCharactersInRange:withString: instead of insertString::atIndex:. You should also set the new selection range appropriately.

Comment: This is great -- but when I do this, the user's cursor gets thrown to the end of the UITextView. How can I keep the user's cursor in place?

Comment: Jason, try tf.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(cursorPosition.location + contentsToAdd.length, 0); after you set the new text

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4**:

```
// lets be safe, thus if-let
if let cursorPosition = textView.selectedTextRange?.start {
    // cursorPosition is a UITextPosition object describing position in the text

    // if you want to know its position in textView in points:
    let caretPositionRect = textView.caretRect(for: cursorPosition)
}
```

We simply use `textView.selectedTextRange` to get selected text range and cursor position is at its `start` position.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `caretRect`.

Answer (score 11):

Use `UITextView selectedRange` property to find the insertion point when the text view is first responder. Otherwise, when the view is not in focus, this property returns `NSNotFound`. If you need to know the cursor position in that case, consider subclassing `UITextView` and overriding `canResignFirstResponder` method, where you can store cursor position to a member variable.

Comment: This is great info that is easy to miss. I can't tell you how long it took my to figure out why the selectedRange.location was returning NSNotFound. 

You can check for invalid location with:
if (myTextField.selectedRange.location == NSNotFound)

Comment: You solved my life! But now i'm wondering, what does `selectedTextRange` meant for? I always get the beginning of the entire text when using it...

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried `UITextView.selectedRange`? It returns an `NSRange`, whose location element should tell you, where the cursor is.