# How to find the location of the cursor in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I want to get the current position of cursor when I first click on a UITextView that contains some text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting cursor position in a UITextView on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618759/getting-cursor-position-in-a-uitextview-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) `selectedRange` property should provide what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

you could use UITextView's selectedRange to return the insertion point pf text.
The below code shows how to it.

```
NSString *contentsToAdd = @"some string";
NSRange cursorPosition = [tf selectedRange];
NSMutableString *tfContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[tf text]];
[tfContent insertString:contentsToAdd atIndex:cursorPosition.location];
[theTextField setText:tfContent];
[tfContent release];
```

for More to read the SO Post

[Getting cursor position in a UITextView on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618759/getting-cursor-position-in-a-uitextview-on-the-iphone)

Also read the same on Apple discussion forum.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9940169