# UITextView cursor positioning

Tags: ios, position, cursor, focus, uitextview

Here is a little tricky problem that I am facing.
With a `UITextView`, I have managed to keep the keyboard away, while still having the focus.

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

When taking the focus, by touching the `UITextView field` with my finger. I can easily have the cursor positioned at the beginning or at the end of the text in the `UITextView field`. But is impossible (or almost) to put the cursor in the middle, with my finger. I want to easily position the cursor anywhere I need (by touching the field); like I could easily do if I was FirstResponder.

Has anyone had this experience and found a solution?

Another way to reach what I want would (probably) be to stay FirstResponder, but not letting the keyboard show up, if that is ever possible.

Just in case it is not clear enough, I am trying to keep the benefit of having a `UITextView` which can get the focus. But I never want to see the keyboard.

Comment: what have you tried so far? does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618759/getting-cursor-position-in-a-uitextview-on-the-iphone?rq=1 not do it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But this is not exactly the info I need. Indeed it is possible to insert text at any position. My issue is not that. What I want is to put my finger in the field at the position I choose and have the cursor at this position, like I could easily do if I was FirstResponder.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to know how to generally place a cursor anywhere? Or like you said in your comment, do you specifically want to place the cursor at the position the user has clicked within the text field? If the second is the case, you really have to update your question quite a bit to clarify.

Comment: I will update the question to make it clearer. Note that it is TextView (not a TextField).

Comment: .... Now updated. I hope it makes the question clear.

Comment: Hm... I've tried to replicate the behavior you're describing but I can't. When I click on a text view, the cursor comes up exactly where I clicked.

Comment: That is what happens when you use the UITextView the usual way (letting it becoming FirstResponder). But if you do what I did, having the focus on UITextView, but with no keyboard showing up then we have the problem. If you did your experiment the way I did, then I really want to know what you did different from me. If you did not do your experiment the way I did, then I need to give you more information to help you reproduce it.

Comment: To Lyndsey Scott, I'd be curious about the way you tried. I have been looking if there could be something on the side causing the UITextView not to work but didn't find any.